# How to add fields to POJO in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have three tables:

```
1. Catalog (PK: id, name, FK: genre_id, FK: type_id)
2. Type (PK: id, name)
3. Genre (PK: id, name)
```

How to use `Hibernate` to connect `Genre` and `Type` to `Catalog` by using annotation?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "catalog")
public class Catalog implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;

    private Genre genre; // to add 
    private Type type;   // to add

    ...
}
```

Comment: This is called a ManyToOne association. The Hibernate documentation explains how they must be mapped. Read it: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect `Genre` and `Type` **to** `Catalog` (is this what you mean?), you should include in both `Genre` and `Type` entities a `Collection<Catalog>`-typed field and annotate it with `@OneToMany`.

If not, the straightest way is to add the `@ManyToOne` annotation to `Genre` and `Type` fields in `Catalog`.

Comment: Should I point some information about connection between Catalog.type_id and Type.id?

Comment: Yes. You will have to add also a `@JoinColumn` annotation (in case you go with the `@ManyToOne` option) and specify the `name` and `referencedColumnName` attributes.